# Why does Time series split cause data leakage from future data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, data-leakage

There are lots of websites saying time series split may cause data leakage.

> The idea for time series splits is to divide the training set into two folds at each iteration on condition that the validation set is always ahead of the training split. At the first iteration, one trains the candidate model on the closing prices from January to March and validates on April’s data, and for the next iteration, train on data from January to April, and validate on May’s data, and so on to the end of the training set. This way dependence is respected.However, this may introduce leakage from future data to the model. The model will observe future patterns to forecast and try to memorize them.
> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R32qg.png)
> [text](https://hub.packtpub.com/cross-validation-strategies-for-time-series-forecasting-tutorial/)

I am confused by these word since the validation set is located after the train set, so it would not cause any problem of data leakage.

In contrast, the article suggests that blocked time series split is better.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmnb.png)